# Login form error react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

I am new to react native, I tried to make login form but I can get password value but not username when I change the position of input component it takes the last one value only and shill I use redux for login form.
This is my code app.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Header, Content, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title, 
 Form, Textarea, Item, Input, Toast } from 'native-base';
import Header1 from './components/Header_sec.js'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '', Password: '' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header1 />
        <Content padder>
          <Form>
            <Text>login</Text>

            <Item>
              <Input onChangeText={(username1) => this.setState({ username : username1 })} placeholder="Username" value={this.state.username} />
              <Text>{this.state.username}</Text>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <Input onChangeText={(Password1) => this.setState({ Password : Password1 })} placeholder="Password" value={this.state.Password} />
              <Text>{this.state.Password}</Text>
            </Item>
            <Button block onPress= {this.myloing.bind(this.state.username,this.state.Password)} >
              <Text>تسجيل الدخول</Text>
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }

  myloing(username,Password) {
    try {
      if (username == "" || Password == "") {
        alert("not allow empty");
        return;
      } else {
        alert(username);
        alert(Password);
      }
    } catch(exc) {
      alert(exc.Text);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Button onPress props to

```js
<Button
  block
  onPress={() => {
    this.myloing(
      this.state.username,
      this.state.Password
    )
  }}
>
```

Comment: thank to you very much it is working now i am still learning the framework